# dojo module dependency(AMD) graph using build

Tags: dojo, amd, dojo-build, dependency-graph

would like to know how to create modular dependent graphs using dojo build system.added below lines in project main profile.js  file.

```
         depsDumpFilename :"dojo-deps-graph",
         depsDumpDotFilename:"dojo-base-json.dot",//used for dependencies graph 
         dotModules:"assets/js",//used for dependencies graph
```

trying to generate AMD graph using dojo Build to get rid of circular dependencies and also to know functional flow.
got basic idea but no real-time examples.
followed http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/build/transforms/depsDump.html#build-transforms-depsdump and http://dojo-reference-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build/profileQRef.html#transform-depsdump

But still not able to get a graph.

As of now am using Madge tool to get graph which is a grate tool to use .but its good to use Dojo Build tool itself.

Can anyone give a good example how can i use dojo Build to generate dependency graph?

Comment: Please post exactly the error you are receiving and what you are trying

Comment: @GibboK : please see updated question.Thanks